# onclick event in HTML <select> not working Chrome and Safari

Tags: javascript, html, forms, google-chrome, safari

I have different JavaScript function associated with each option tag to toggle layers on/off in an OpenLayers map. It works fine Opera, Firefox and IE9, but not in Chrome and Safari. I read that I could use onchange on the select tag, but since I'm new to JavaScript, I don't really how it would call four different functions?

```
<select size="1" name="usgsfeed" id="usgsfeed">
<option value="usgs_hour" onclick="display_usgs_hour();">Past hour, all earthquakes</option>
<option value="usgs_day" onclick="display_usgs_day();" SELECTED>Past day, magnitude > 1</option>
<option value="usgs_week" onclick="display_usgs_week();">Past week, magnitude > 2.5</option>
<option value="usgs_month" onclick="display_usgs_month();">Past month, magnitude > 2.5</option>
<option value="none" onclick="display_none();">None</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Call the function according to the select's value:

```
<select onchange="window['display_'+this.value]();">
```

If the value is `"usgs_hour"` the concatenation would be `'display_' + 'usgs_hour' === 'display_usgs_hour'` and that function is called.

jsfiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Ag3kh/

Comment: +1. I was about to post a similar answer. Here's the fiddle I created: http://jsfiddle.net/Ag3kh/

Comment: You will need a 0th option or hours can only be displayed if something else is selected first

Answer (score 2):

use switch construction for selected value

```
$('#usgsfeed').change(function () {
    swith($(this).val()) {
    case 'usgs_hour':
        display_usgs_hour();
        break;.....
    }
})
```

Comment: If you are going to assume the OP can use jQuery why not get the selected value with `$(this).val()`?

Comment: Not always is jquery available.

Comment: Not always is jquery available - javascript solution exist too :) But jQuery it'is easy
If you are going to assume the OP can use jQuery why not get the selected value with $(this).val() - yes, it's easier

Comment: @Andrey It can exists some restrictions from administration to avoid the use of Jquery.

Comment: @reporter I am understand you. If jQuery not figured in question, i am do not post this to the answer. :)

Comment: I think it's OK to suggest a jQuery solution even if jQuery isn't mentioned in the question, but you should explicitly say that it is a jQuery solution or the OP (who mentioned being new to JS) won't be able to use it. For this question though the non-JS version of your code would be the same number of lines, so jQuery gives minimal advantage...

Answer (score 1):

you should indeed use onchange!

To do this in javascript (not jquery) this would work:

JavaScript:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

function SelectChanged()  {  
    if (document.aform.usgsfeed.value == "usgs_hour")  {
        alert("usgs_hour chosen");
    else if( ...etc) 
    }  
 }

</script>
```

HTML:

```
<form name="aform">
    <select size="1" name="usgsfeed" id="usgsfeed"  onchange='SelectChanged();>
        <option value="usgs_hour">Past hour, all earthquakes</option>
        <option value="usgs_day" SELECTED>Past day, magnitude > 1</option>
        <option value="usgs_week">Past week, magnitude > 2.5</option>
        <option value="usgs_month">Past month, magnitude > 2.5</option>
        <option value="none">None</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: You don't need `javascript:` at the beginning of your event attribute.

Comment: Only need for javascript: label if the first script on the page is vbscript. Otherwise no need ever.

Comment: @mplungjan that doesn't make any sense. It might as well say `asdasdasdad:` since it's just a dead label

Comment: In IE, the label IS used. If there is a vbscript in the head of the page, the default scripting language is set to vbscript and you need to use the javascript: label on all event handlers that contain JavaScript, I did not make that up. Here is a bigger [discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10068781/what-does-the-javascript-pseudo-protocol-actually-do)

Comment: @mplungjan Well it certainly doesn't make sense because it's supposed to be a label and not contain any side-information like what language to use. On the other hand, I suppose it kinda makes sense since it's IE. :P

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the jsFiddle demo: [jsfiddle.net/bWdaU/](http://jsfiddle.net/bWdaU/).

It uses `onchange` to call the function `display_usgs_change`.

I have added a temporary `<div>` to show the selection working.

**HTML:**

```
<select id="usgsfeed" name="usgsfeed" size="1" onchange="display_usgs_change();">
    <option value="usgs_hour">Past hour, all earthquakes</option>
    <option value="usgs_day" selected="selected">Past day, magnitude > 1</option>
    <option value="usgs_week">Past week, magnitude > 2.5</option>
    <option value="usgs_month">Past month, magnitude > 2.5</option>
    <option value="none">None</option>
</select>
<div id="dummy">Remove this div!</div>​
```

**JS:**

```
function display_usgs_change() {
    document.getElementById('dummy').innerHTML = event.target.value;
}​
```