# Javascript Button Redirect

Tags: javascript, html

Trying to get my button to act like a link (tried the `<A>` tag and it would work if you open in a new tab but not if you click on it. Then tried this code and nothing.  Suggestions?

```
<button onClick="location.href='/secure/edit.aspx?id=671'">Edit</button>
```

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/NTICompass/vFfq3/1/

Answer (score 15):

You need to explicitly say `window.location` because `this` in the context of the button is the button object itself. Ordinarily, JavaScript is run in the context of the `window` object, so you don't need to do that.

```
<button onClick="javascript:window.location.href='/secure/edit.aspx?id=671'">Edit</button>
```

(Additionally, I also like to explicitly state that the script is `javascript:`, but that's purely a personal thing.)

Comment: The `javascript` label is useless.

Comment: Redundant, not useless. See https://gist.github.com/3770452 However, why I like to include it is because I believe it improves readability.

Comment: Depends on language. In US English, redundant is often used to mean "backup" or "failover" (e.g. a redundant system for emergency power). In other versions of English, redundant means unnecessary or surplus to requirements, so it's a synonym for useless. :-)

Comment: It's misleading. It doesn't specify the language, it provides a [place to break or continue to](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label).

Comment: @Quentin Jun, it actually does (or did?) in IE, see the example above or here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10068781/what-does-the-javascript-pseudo-protocol-actually-do ... but, I use it for readability.

Answer (score 7):

```
<button onclick="window.location='/secure/edit.aspx?id=671'">Edit</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with window.location

```
<button onClick="window.location='/secure/edit.aspx?id=671'">Edit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `type = "button"`

```
<button type = "button" onClick="window.location='/secure/edit.aspx?id=671'">Edit</button>
```

You need to add the `type`, otherwise the button will act as a submit button and will POST your form instead of redirecting to the desired url.