# onclick javascript function does not work with Firefox/IE

Tags: javascript, html, button, onclick, reload

I have a problem with my Captcha reload action. It works very well with Chrome but not with Firefox or IE.
There is a Captcha and a Button and I want to refresh the Captcha without reloading the entire page. I would be happy if I could get some help with this.
**head with javascript code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' />
        <link href='resources/styles.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
        <title>...</title>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            function reloadCaptcha()
            {
                img = document.getElementById('captcha');
                img.src = 'resources/templates/captcha/Captcha.php';
            }
        </script>
    </head>
```

**captcha and refresh button:**

```
<img src="resources/templates/captcha/Captcha.php" id='captcha'>
    <a href="#" onclick='javascript:reloadCaptcha();'>
        <img src="../backend/resources/media/captcha_refresh.png">
    </a>
```

Comment: onclick can ONLY run Javascript. using "javascript:" is redundant.

Comment: in the console what error are you getting? function reloadCaptcha() undefined???? or you script has not effect?, try include in your script an alert('xxx'); to see it is running

Comment: While you don't need the `javascript:` part, it should still execute. Perhaps the browser is caching the image since you're not changing the img src to something new. Does it work if you call the function manually from the console?

Comment: alert works, has to be something with the img

Comment: you need to return false!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the problem might be caching. You can fix this by adding a timestamp to your new `img src`, like this:

```
function reloadCaptcha() {
    var img = document.getElementById('captcha'),
        timestamp = new Date().getTime();
    img.src = 'resources/templates/captcha/Captcha.php?' + timestamp;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped. The only problem now is, if I spam hit the button, it doesn't refresh, but it should be fine like that.

Comment: Yes, depending on your browser the timestamp is only updated every 15-60 milliseconds. Unfortunately Javascript's built-in random number generator has the same problem. You can work around this by adding some code to detect duplicates but it probably isn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is bad.

Option 1:

```
<a href="javascript:reloadCaptcha();">
```

Option 2:

```
<a href="#" onclick='reloadCaptcha();'>
```

Option 3: use the EventHandler API.

Comment: Never ever use the javascript: protocol in the href - it partially unloads the page and has many other drawbacks

Comment: The syntax is not at fault here. The `javascript:` part in the event handler will just be ignored. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321469/when-do-i-need-to-specify-the-javascript-protocol

Comment: @mplungjan do you have a source for that claim?

Comment: the href:javascript will certainly NOT be ignored! the onclick="javascript: will

Comment: are you sure @mplungjan? I prefer the a href=javascript solution. Does not change my url and refreshes just fine.

Comment: Absolutely. Here is a rundown of what javascript: protocol and label does http://stackoverflow.com/a/10069139/295783

Comment: I have just tested I have to admit that is seems to have less impact on the newest Chrome and FX than it used to have. I'll have a look at IE8 and 10 on Windows tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

As well as avoiding caching you need to return false in the onclick

```
<a href="#" 
onclick='reloadCaptcha(); return false'><img 
src="../backend/resources/media/captcha_refresh.png"></a>
```

Comment: Your description of the problem was poor. You need to avoid caching to refresh but also return false to not follow the link

Comment: Sorry, I didn't have a clue what the problem was. I tried to get out what I had. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem on Firefox and Internet Explorer. I used event handler and I solved my problem. Use

```
evt.preventDefault(); 
return false;
```

In your javascript functions.